# NodeJS connect to Confluent Cloud Kafka using openID with SASL extension

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, sasl, confluent-cloud

I'm trying to connect to a **Confluent Cloud** Kafka server which is configured with OpenID identity provider using NodeJS.

see: https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/access-management/authenticate/oauth/configure-clients-oauth.html#client-login-callback-handler-top-level-configuration-options

I'm able to connect when using the `kafka-console-consumer` command (like the confluent cloud example)

```
# ./kafka.properties
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=OAUTHBEARER
sasl.login.callback.handler.class=org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.secured.OAuthBearerLoginCallbackHandler
sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms=15000
sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url=https://myidp.example.com/oauth2/default/v1/token
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule required \
    clientId="MY_CLIENT_ID" \
    clientSecret="MY_CLIETN_SECRET" \
    scope="SCOPE" \
    extension_logicalCluster="CLUSTER_ID" \
    extension_identityPoolId="IDENTITY_POOL_ID" ;
```

```bash
kafka-console-consumer \
        --bootstrap-server KAFKA_BROKER \
        --consumer.config ./kafka.properties \
        --topic MY_TOPIC \
        --group GROUP_NAME
```

Currently I'm following KafkaJS oauthbearer example https://kafka.js.org/docs/configuration#oauthbearer-example but I'm getting lost when trying to introduce `SASL extension` to the mix (i.e extension_logicalCluster and extension_identityPoolId) .

My code so far

```
# oauthBearerProviderOpenId.ts
import { Issuer, TokenSet } from 'openid-client';

export interface oauthBearerProviderOpenIdOptions {
    issuer: string;
    clientId: string;
    clientSecret: string;
    refreshThresholdMs: number;
    scope: string,
    logicalCluster: string,
    identityPoolId: string,
}

export const oauthBearerProviderOpenId = async (options: oauthBearerProviderOpenIdOptions) => {
    const issuer = await Issuer.discover(options.issuer);
    const { Client } = issuer;

    const client = new Client({
        client_id: options.clientId,
        client_secret: options.clientSecret,
    });

    let tokenPromise: Promise<string>;
    let tokenSet: TokenSet | null;

    async function refreshToken() {
        try {
            if (tokenSet == null) {
                tokenSet = await client.grant({
                    grant_type: 'client_credentials',
                    scope: options.scope,
                });
            }

            setTimeout(() => {
                tokenPromise = refreshToken()
            }, tokenSet!.expires_in);

            if(!tokenSet.access_token) {
                throw new Error('Unable to fetch access_token');
            }
            
            return tokenSet.access_token;

        } catch (error) {
            const e = error as any;
            tokenSet = null;
            console.error(e.data.payload.toString());
            throw error;
        }
    }

    tokenPromise = refreshToken();

    return async function () {
        return {
            value: await tokenPromise
        }
    }
};
```

ERROR LOG

```
SASL OAUTHBEARER authentication failed: Authentication failed: 1 extensions are invalid! They are: logicalCluster: CLUSTER_ID_MISSING_OR_EMPTY
KafkaJSSASLAuthenticationError: SASL OAUTHBEARER authentication failed: Authentication failed: 1 extensions are invalid! They are: logicalCluster: CLUSTER_ID_MISSING_OR_EMPTY
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging into KafkaJS code I found out KafkaJS dose support SASL extensions. (see: https://github.com/tulios/kafkajs/blob/ff3b1117f316d527ae170b550bc0f772614338e9/src/protocol/sasl/oauthBearer/request.js#LL50C53-L50C53)

To pass the SASL extensions use the following code (Based on KafkaJS oauthBearerProvider example https://kafka.js.org/docs/configuration#oauthbearer-example).

```
import { AccessToken, ClientCredentials } from "simple-oauth2";

export interface OauthBearerProviderOptions {
  clientId: string;
  clientSecret: string;
  host: string;
  path: string;
  refreshThresholdMs: number;
  scope?: string,
  saslExtension?: { [key: string]: string }
}

export const oauthBearerProvider = (options: OauthBearerProviderOptions) => {
  const client = new ClientCredentials({
    client: {
      id: options.clientId,
      secret: options.clientSecret
    },
    auth: {
      tokenHost: options.host,
      tokenPath: options.path
    },
    options: {
      authorizationMethod: 'body',
    },
  });

  let tokenPromise: Promise<string>;
  let accessToken: AccessToken | null;

  async function refreshToken() {
    try {
      if (accessToken == null) {
        accessToken = await client.getToken({
          scope: options.scope,
        });
      }

      if (accessToken.expired(options.refreshThresholdMs / 1000)) {
        accessToken = await accessToken.refresh()
      }

      const nextRefresh = (accessToken.token.expires_in as number) * 1000 - options.refreshThresholdMs;
      setTimeout(() => {
        tokenPromise = refreshToken()
      }, nextRefresh);

      return accessToken.token.access_token as string;
    } catch (error) {
      const e = error as any;
      accessToken = null;
      console.error(e.data.payload.toString());
      throw error;
    }
  }

  tokenPromise = refreshToken();

  return async function () {
    return {
      value: await tokenPromise,
      extensions: options.saslExtension // <--- pass sasl extension as key value
    }
  }
};
```

sasl extensions object example

```json
{
   "logicalCluster": "<CLUSTER_ID>",
   "identityPoolId": "<IDENTITY_POOL_ID>"
}
```